# How to configure Dokka for package documentation using Gradle?

Tags: gradle, kotlin-dokka

I am unable to configure Dokka to include the documentation of my packages without using a full absolute path from the root of the file system. I have in my Gradle file (the `includes` line is the one in problem):

```
dokka {
    outputFormat = 'html'
    outputDirectory = "$projectDir/../doc"


    configuration {
        // Use to include or exclude non public members.
        includeNonPublic = false

        // Do not output deprecated members. Applies globally, can be overridden by packageOptions
        skipDeprecated = false

        // Emit warnings about not documented members. Applies globally, also can be overridden by packageOptions
        reportUndocumented = true

        // Do not create index pages for empty packages
        skipEmptyPackages = true

        includes = ["${projectDir}/app/src/main/kotlin/com/biexpertise/simplewebview/packages.md"]
    }
}
```

When, I run `./gradlew dokka` if I have this error:

```
> Task :app:dokka FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dokka'.
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

If I remove `$projectDir` and use an absolute path, things are working. It is possible to use a relative path instead?

Answer (score 0):

So that's in fact a problem with dokka's Gradle plugin, or to be more specific, with Groovy String implementation. Groovy uses it's own `GStringImpl` for strings, instead of the `String` class, which leads to a problem when casting a `List<GStringImpl>` to `List<String>` (this cast doesn't succeed).

The easiest solution is to call `.toString()` on your include, like this:

```
includes = ["${projectDir}/app/src/main/kotlin/com/biexpertise/simplewebview/packages.md".toString()]
```

This should be fixed on the dokka side though, you can file a bug report on GitHub