# How to modify build.gradle.kts sourceSets for Dokka task?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dokka, source-sets

I am using the Dokka plugin in `build.gradle.kts`. I am able to generate the Dokka HTML for my source code but have been unable to figure out how to configure the task to include `package.md` files that document packages. (I am not using modules.)

I tried this:

```
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaTask>().configureEach {
    dokkaSourceSets {
        named("main") {
            includes.from("package.md")
        }
    }
}
```

I received an error because there was no `package.md` file in the root directory.

I also tried this line, but the wildcards were not expanded:

```
includes.from("src/**/package.md")
```

How do I instruct Gradle to include all files named `package.md`, regardless of their directory, the way it includes all Kotlin source code, regardless of directory?

This differs from [How to configure Dokka for package documentation using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59307514/how-to-configure-dokka-for-package-documentation-using-gradle), which uses Groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer on the Kotlin Slack:

```
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.dokka.gradle.DokkaTask>().configureEach {
    dokkaSourceSets {
        named("main") {
            includes.from(fileTree(project.rootDir) {
                include("src/**/package.md")
            })
        }
    }
}
```